# Creating std::span from pybind array

Tags: c++, c++20, pybind11

```
void createSpanfromNumpy(pybind11::array_t<int>& inputA, std::vector<int>& inputB)
{
    auto addressA = inputA.data();

    auto addressB = inputB.data();

    std::span<int> testSpanA{ inputA.data(), inputA.size()};


    std::span<int> testSpanB{ inputB.data(), inputB.size() };

    //do stuff with span

}
```

Trying to grab references to the memory used in a numpy array and pass them around in C++ for convenience. In the example code above it works fine for a std::vector but when trying to create a span from numpy array (inputA), this compiler error is produced:

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::span<int,4294967295>'   numpytoSpan
```

What is it about the pointer coming out of the array_t.data() call which doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputA.data()` is a `const int*`.

Use a `std::span<const int>` or use `pybind11::array_t::mutable_data`.